# makeinfo: Error: Dumper.c: loadable library and perl binaries are mismatched (got handshake key 0xdb00080, needed 0xcd00080)

Tags: c, perl

Tengo un problema con un comando, el `makeinfo`, enlazado hacia `texi2any`, da error.

`makeinfo`:

> perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
> perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
> LANGUAGE = (unset),
> LC_ALL = (unset),
> LANG = "es_AR.UTF-8"
> are supported and installed on your system.
> perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
> Encode.c: loadable library and perl binaries are mismatched (got handshake key 0xeb00080, needed 0xcd00080)

`autom4te`:

> perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
> perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
> LANGUAGE = (unset),
> LC_ALL = (unset),
> LANG = "es_AR.UTF-8"
> are supported and installed on your system.
> perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
> Dumper.c: loadable library and perl binaries are mismatched (got handshake key 0xdb00080, needed 0xcd00080)

El script de bash `/usr/bin/autoconf` necesita `/usr/bin/autom4te` (se pronunciaría *automate* o *autom for te*)... Este último es el script de *Perl* que causa el error.

***/usr/bin/autom4te*** (archivo de 767 líneas)

```pl
#! /usr/bin/perl -w

# -*- perl -*-
# Generated from autom4te.in; do not edit by hand.

eval 'case $# in 0) exec /usr/bin/perl -S "$0";; *) exec /usr/bin/perl -S "$0" "$@";; esac'
    if 0;

# autom4te - Wrapper around M4 libraries.
# Copyright (C) 2001-2003, 2005-2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

# This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.

# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.

# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.


BEGIN
{
  my $pkgdatadir = $ENV{'autom4te_perllibdir'} || '/usr/share/autoconf';
  unshift @INC, $pkgdatadir;
  $ENV{'SHELL'} = '/bin/sh' if ($^O eq 'dos');
}

use Autom4te::C4che;
use Autom4te::ChannelDefs;
use Autom4te::Channels;
use Autom4te::FileUtils;
use Autom4te::General;
use Autom4te::XFile;
use File::Basename;
use strict;

my $pkgdatadir = $ENV{'AC_MACRODIR'} || '/usr/share/autoconf';
my %language;
my $output = '-';
my $mode = "0666";
my $melt = 0;
my $cache;
my $icache;
my $tcache;
my $ocache;
my $icache_file;
my $flock_implemented = 'yes';
my %trace;
my @preselect = ('include',
         'm4_pattern_allow', 'm4_pattern_forbid',
         '_m4_warn');
my @include;
my $freeze = 0;
my $m4 = $ENV{"M4"} || '/usr/bin/m4';

fatal "need GNU m4 1.4 or later: $m4"
  if system "$m4 --help </dev/null 2>&1 | grep reload-state >/dev/null";

$m4 .= ' --nesting-limit=1024'
  if " $m4 " !~ / (--nesting-limit(=[0-9]+)?|-L[0-9]*) /;

my @m4_builtin = `echo dumpdef | $m4 2>&1 >/dev/null`;
map { s/:.*//;s/\W// } @m4_builtin;

my %m4_builtin_alternate_name;
@m4_builtin_alternate_name{"$_", "m4_$_"} = ("m4_$_", "$_")
  foreach (grep { !/m4wrap|m4exit|dnl|ifelse|__.*__/ } @m4_builtin);
@m4_builtin_alternate_name{"ifelse", "m4_if"}   = ("m4_if", "ifelse");
@m4_builtin_alternate_name{"m4exit", "m4_exit"} = ("m4_exit", "m4exit");
@m4_builtin_alternate_name{"m4wrap", "m4_wrap"} = ("m4_wrap", "m4wrap");

$help = "Usage: $0 [OPTION]... [FILES]

Run GNU M4 on the FILES, avoiding useless runs.  Output the traces if tracing,
the frozen file if freezing, otherwise the expansion of the FILES.

If some of the FILES are named \`FILE.m4f\' they are considered to be M4
frozen files of all the previous files (which are therefore not loaded).
If \`FILE.m4f\' is not found, then \`FILE.m4\' will be used, together with
all the previous files.

Some files may be optional, i.e., will only be processed if found in the
include path, but then must end in \`.m4?\';  the question mark is not part of
the actual file name.

Operation modes:
  -h, --help               print this help, then exit
  -V, --version            print version number, then exit
  -v, --verbose            verbosely report processing
  -d, --debug              don\'t remove temporary files
  -o, --output=FILE        save output in FILE (defaults to \`-\', stdout)
  -f, --force              don\'t rely on cached values
  -W, --warnings=CATEGORY  report the warnings falling in CATEGORY
  -l, --language=LANG      specify the set of M4 macros to use
  -C, --cache=DIRECTORY    preserve results for future runs in DIRECTORY
      --no-cache           disable the cache
  -m, --mode=OCTAL         change the non trace output file mode (0666)
  -M, --melt               don\'t use M4 frozen files

Languages include:
  \`Autoconf\'   create Autoconf configure scripts
  \`Autotest\'   create Autotest test suites
  \`M4sh\'       create M4sh shell scripts
  \`M4sugar\'    create M4sugar output

" . Autom4te::ChannelDefs::usage . "

The environment variables \`M4\' and \`WARNINGS\' are honored.

Library directories:
  -B, --prepend-include=DIR  prepend directory DIR to search path
  -I, --include=DIR          append directory DIR to search path

Tracing:
  -t, --trace=MACRO[:FORMAT]  report the MACRO invocations
  -p, --preselect=MACRO       prepare to trace MACRO in a future run

Freezing:
  -F, --freeze   produce an M4 frozen state file for FILES

FORMAT defaults to \`\$f:\$l:\$n:\$%\', and can use the following escapes:
  \$\$     literal \$
  \$f     file where macro was called
  \$l     line where macro was called
  \$d     nesting depth of macro call
  \$n     name of the macro
  \$NUM   argument NUM, unquoted and with newlines
  \$SEP\@  all arguments, with newlines, quoted, and separated by SEP
  \$SEP*  all arguments, with newlines, unquoted, and separated by SEP
  \$SEP%  all arguments, without newlines, unquoted, and separated by SEP
SEP can be empty for the default (comma for \@ and *, colon for %),
a single character for that character, or {STRING} to use a string.

Report bugs to <bug-autoconf\@gnu.org>.
GNU Autoconf home page: <http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/>.
General help using GNU software: <http://www.gnu.org/gethelp/>.
";

$version =  <<"EOF";
autom4te (GNU Autoconf) 2.69
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+/Autoconf: GNU GPL version 3 or later
<http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>, <http://gnu.org/licenses/exceptions.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Akim Demaille.
EOF

sub files_to_options (@)
{
  my (@file) = @_;
  my @res;
  foreach my $file (@file)
    {
      my $arg = shell_quote ($file);
      if ($file =~ /\.m4f$/)
    {
      $arg = "--reload-state=$arg";
      $arg .= " --undefine=__m4_version__"
        unless grep {/__m4_version__/} @m4_builtin;
    }
      push @res, $arg;
    }
  return join ' ', @res;
}

sub load_configuration ($)
{
  my ($file) = @_;
  use Text::ParseWords;

  my $cfg = new Autom4te::XFile ("< " . open_quote ($file));
  my $lang;
  while ($_ = $cfg->getline)
    {
      chomp;
      next
    if /^\s*(\#.*)?$/;

      my @words = shellwords ($_);
      my $type = shift @words;
      if ($type eq 'begin-language:')
    {
      fatal "$file:$.: end-language missing for: $lang"
        if defined $lang;
      $lang = lc $words[0];
    }
      elsif ($type eq 'end-language:')
    {
      error "$file:$.: end-language mismatch: $lang"
        if $lang ne lc $words[0];
      $lang = undef;
    }
      elsif ($type eq 'args:')
    {
      fatal "$file:$.: no current language"
        unless defined $lang;
      push @{$language{$lang}}, @words;
    }
      else
    {
      error "$file:$.: unknown directive: $type";
    }
    }
}

sub parse_args ()
{
  my @language;
  do {
    @language = ();
    use Getopt::Long;
    Getopt::Long::Configure ("pass_through", "permute");
    GetOptions ("l|language=s" => \@language);

    foreach (@language)
      {
    error "unknown language: $_"
      unless exists $language{lc $_};
    unshift @ARGV, @{$language{lc $_}};
      }
  } while @language;

  if (exists $ENV{'AUTOM4TE_DEBUG'})
    {
      print STDERR "$me: concrete arguments:\n";
      foreach my $arg (@ARGV)
    {
      print STDERR "| $arg\n";
    }
    }

  my @trace;
  my @prepend_include;
  parse_WARNINGS;
  getopt
    (
     "o|output=s"   => \$output,
     "W|warnings=s" => \&parse_warnings,
     "m|mode=s"     => \$mode,
     "M|melt"       => \$melt,
     "B|prepend-include=s" => \@prepend_include,
     "I|include=s"         => \@include,
     "t|trace=s"     => \@trace,
     "p|preselect=s" => \@preselect,
     "F|freeze" => \$freeze,
     "C|cache=s" => \$cache,
     "no-cache"  => sub { $cache = undef; },
    );

  fatal "too few arguments
Try `$me --help' for more information."
    unless @ARGV;

  fatal "cannot freeze and trace"
    if $freeze && @trace;
  $melt = 1
    if $freeze;

  $cache = $tmp
    unless $cache;
  $icache = "$cache/requests";
  $tcache = "$cache/traces.";
  $ocache = "$cache/output.";

  @include = grep { !/^\.$/ } uniq (reverse(@prepend_include), @include);

  foreach (@trace)
    {
      /^([^:]+)(?::(.*))?$/ms;
      $trace{$1} = defined $2 ? $2 : '$f:$l:$n:$%';
      $trace{$m4_builtin_alternate_name{$1}} = $trace{$1}
    if exists $m4_builtin_alternate_name{$1};
    }

  push (@preselect,
    map { $m4_builtin_alternate_name{$_} }
    grep { exists $m4_builtin_alternate_name{$_} } @preselect);

  my @argv;
  foreach (@ARGV)
    {
      if ($_ eq '-')
    {
      push @argv, $_;
    }
      elsif (/\.m4f$/)
    {
      my $file = find_file ("$_?", @include);
      if (!$melt && $file)
        {
          @argv = ($file);
        }
      else
        {
          s/\.m4f$/.m4/;
          push @argv, find_file ($_, @include);
        }
    }
      else
    {
      my $file = find_file ($_, @include);
      push @argv, $file
        if $file;
    }
    }
  @ARGV = @argv;
}

sub handle_m4 ($@)
{
  my ($req, @macro) = @_;

  unlink ($tcache . $req->id . "t");

  xsystem ("$m4 --gnu"
       . join (' --include=', '', map { shell_quote ($_) } @include)
       . ' --debug=aflq'
       . (!exists $ENV{'AUTOM4TE_NO_FATAL'} ? ' --fatal-warning' : '')
       . " --debugfile=" . shell_quote ("$tcache" . $req->id . "t")
       . join (' --trace=', '', map { shell_quote ($_) } sort @macro)
       . " " . files_to_options (@ARGV)
       . " > " . shell_quote ("$ocache" . $req->id . "t"));

  foreach my $file (map { $_ . $req->id } ($tcache, $ocache))
    {
      use File::Copy;
      move ("${file}t", "$file")
    or fatal "cannot rename ${file}t as $file: $!";
    }
}

my $first_warn_forbidden = 1;
sub warn_forbidden ($$%)
{
  my ($where, $word, %forbidden) = @_;
  my $message;

  for my $re (sort keys %forbidden)
    {
      if ($word =~ $re)
    {
      $message = $forbidden{$re};
      last;
    }
    }
  $message ||= "possibly undefined macro: $word";
  warn "$where: error: $message\n";
  if ($first_warn_forbidden)
    {
      warn <<EOF;
      If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
      See the Autoconf documentation.
EOF
      $first_warn_forbidden = 0;
    }
}

sub handle_output ($$)
{
  my ($req, $output) = @_;

  verb "creating $output";

  handle_traces ($req, "$tmp/patterns",
         ('m4_pattern_forbid' => 'forbid:$1:$2',
          'm4_pattern_allow'  => 'allow:$1'));
  my @patterns = new Autom4te::XFile ("< " . open_quote ("$tmp/patterns"))->getlines;
  chomp @patterns;
  my %forbidden =
    map { /^forbid:([^:]+):.+$/ => /^forbid:[^:]+:(.+)$/ } @patterns;
  my $forbidden = join ('|', map { /^forbid:([^:]+)/ } @patterns) || "^\$";
  my $allowed   = join ('|', map { /^allow:([^:]+)/  } @patterns) || "^\$";

  verb "forbidden tokens: $forbidden";
  verb "forbidden token : $_ => $forbidden{$_}"
    foreach (sort keys %forbidden);
  verb "allowed   tokens: $allowed";

  my $out = new Autom4te::XFile;
  my $atomic_replace;
  if ($output eq '-' || (-e $output && ! -f $output))
    {
      $out->open (">$output");
      $atomic_replace = 0;
    }
  else
    {
      $out->open("$output.tmp", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC, oct ($mode));
      if ($out) {
        $atomic_replace = 1;
      } else {
        $out->open($output, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC, oct ($mode));
        $atomic_replace = 0;
      }
    }
  fatal "cannot create $output: $!"
    unless $out;
  my $in = new Autom4te::XFile ("< " . open_quote ($ocache . $req->id));

  my %prohibited;
  my $res;
  while ($_ = $in->getline)
    {
      s/\s+$//;
      s/__oline__/$./g;
      s/\@<:\@/[/g;
      s/\@:>\@/]/g;
      s/\@\{:\@/(/g;
      s/\@:\}\@/)/g;
      s/\@S\|\@/\$/g;
      s/\@%:\@/#/g;

      $res = $_;

      s/\#.*//
    unless /^\#\s*(if|include|endif|ifdef|ifndef|define)\b/;
      foreach (split (/\W+/))
    {
      $prohibited{$_} = $.
        if !/^$/ && /$forbidden/o && !/$allowed/o && ! exists $prohibited{$_};
    }
      $res =~ s/\@&t\@//g;

      print $out "$res\n";
    }

  $out->close();

  if ($atomic_replace && !rename("$output.tmp", "$output")) {
    move ("${output}.tmp", "$output")
      or fatal "cannot rename ${output}.tmp as $output: $!";
  }

  return
    if ! %prohibited;

  $exit_code = 1;
  if ($ARGV[$#ARGV] ne '-')
    {
      my $prohibited = '\b(' . join ('|', keys %prohibited) . ')\b';
      my $file = new Autom4te::XFile ("< " . open_quote ($ARGV[$#ARGV]));

      while ($_ = $file->getline)
    {
      s/\#.*//
        unless /^\#(if|include|endif|ifdef|ifndef|define)\b/;

      while (/$prohibited/)
        {
          my $word = $1;
          warn_forbidden ("$ARGV[$#ARGV]:$.", $word, %forbidden);
          delete $prohibited{$word};
          return
        if ! %prohibited;
          $prohibited = '\b(' . join ('|', keys %prohibited) . ')\b';
        }
    }
    }
  warn_forbidden ("$output:$prohibited{$_}", $_, %forbidden)
    foreach (sort { $prohibited{$a} <=> $prohibited{$b} } keys %prohibited);
}

sub trace_format_to_m4 ($)
{
  my ($format) = @_;
  my $underscore = $_;
  my %escape = (
        'f' => '$1',
        'l' => '$2',
        'd' => '$3',
        'n' => '$4',
        '$' => '$');

  my $res = '';
  $_ = $format;
  while ($_)
    {
      if (s/^\$(\d+)//)
    {
      $res .= "\$" . ($1 + 4);
    }
      elsif (s/^\$([fldn\$])//)
    {
      $res .= $escape{$1};
    }
      elsif (s/^\$\{([^}]*)\}([@*%])//
        || s/^\$(.?)([@*%])//)
    {
      if ($2 eq '@')
        {
          $res .= ']at_at([' . ($1 ? $1 : ',') . '], $@)[';
        }
      elsif ($2 eq '*')
        {
          $res .= ']at_star([' . ($1 ? $1 : ',') . '], $@)[';
        }
      elsif ($2 eq '%')
        {
          $res .= ']at_percent([' . ($1 ? $1 : ':') . '], $@)[';
        }
    }
      elsif (/^(\$.)/)
    {
      error "invalid escape: $1";
    }
      else
    {
      s/^([^\$]+)//;
      $res .= $1;
    }
    }

  $_ = $underscore;
  return '[[' . $res . ']]';
}

sub handle_traces ($$%)
{
  my ($req, $output, %trace) = @_;

  verb "formatting traces for `$output': " . join (', ', sort keys %trace);

  my $trace_m4 = new Autom4te::XFile ("> " . open_quote ("$tmp/traces.m4"));

  $_ = <<'EOF';
  divert(-1)
  changequote([, ])
  # _at_MODE(SEPARATOR, ELT1, ELT2...)
  # ----------------------------------
  # List the elements, separating then with SEPARATOR.
  # MODE can be:
  #  `at'       -- the elements are enclosed in brackets.
  #  `star'     -- the elements are listed as are.
  #  `percent'  -- the elements are `flattened': spaces are singled out,
  #                and no new line remains.
  define([_at_at],
  [at_ifelse([$#], [1], [],
         [$#], [2], [[[$2]]],
         [[[$2]][$1]$0([$1], at_shift(at_shift($@)))])])

  define([_at_percent],
  [at_ifelse([$#], [1], [],
         [$#], [2], [at_flatten([$2])],
         [at_flatten([$2])[$1]$0([$1], at_shift(at_shift($@)))])])

  define([_at_star],
  [at_ifelse([$#], [1], [],
         [$#], [2], [[$2]],
         [[$2][$1]$0([$1], at_shift(at_shift($@)))])])

  # FLATTEN quotes its result.
  # Note that the second pattern is `newline, tab or space'.  Don't lose
  # the tab!
  define([at_flatten],
  [at_patsubst(at_patsubst([[[$1]]], [\\\n]), [[\n\t ]+], [ ])])

  define([at_args],    [at_shift(at_shift(at_shift(at_shift(at_shift($@)))))])
  define([at_at],      [_$0([$1], at_args($@))])
  define([at_percent], [_$0([$1], at_args($@))])
  define([at_star],    [_$0([$1], at_args($@))])

EOF
  s/^  //mg;s/\\t/\t/mg;s/\\n/\n/mg;
  print $trace_m4 $_;

  print $trace_m4 "# Copy the builtins.\n";
  map { print $trace_m4 "define([at_$_], defn([$_]))\n" } @m4_builtin;
  print $trace_m4 "\n";

  print $trace_m4 "# Disable them.\n";
  map { print $trace_m4 "at_undefine([$_])\n" } @m4_builtin;
  print $trace_m4 "\n";

  print $trace_m4
   "## -------------------------------------- ##\n",
   "## By default neutralize all the traces.  ##\n",
   "## -------------------------------------- ##\n",
   "\n";
  print $trace_m4 "at_define([AT_$_], [at_dnl])\n"
    foreach (sort keys %{$req->macro});
  print $trace_m4 "\n";

  print $trace_m4
    "## ------------------------- ##\n",
    "## Trace processing macros.  ##\n",
    "## ------------------------- ##\n",
    "\n";
  foreach (sort keys %trace)
    {
      (my $comment = "Trace $_:$trace{$_}") =~ s/^/\# /;
      print $trace_m4 "$comment\n";
      print $trace_m4 "at_define([AT_$_],\n";
      print $trace_m4 trace_format_to_m4 ($trace{$_}) . ")\n\n";
    }
  print $trace_m4 "\n";
  print $trace_m4 "at_divert(0)at_dnl\n";

  my $traces = new Autom4te::XFile ("< " . open_quote ($tcache . $req->id));
  while ($_ = $traces->getline)
    {
      s{^m4trace:(.+):(\d+): -(\d+)- ([^(]+)\((.*)$}
       {AT_$4([$1], [$2], [$3], [$4], $5};

      s{^m4trace:(.+):(\d+): -(\d+)- ([^)]*)\n$}
       {AT_$4([$1], [$2], [$3], [$4])\n};
      print $trace_m4 "$_";
    }
  $trace_m4->close;

  my $in = new Autom4te::XFile ("$m4 " . shell_quote ("$tmp/traces.m4") . " |");
  my $out = new Autom4te::XFile ("> " . open_quote ($output));

  while ($_ = $in->getline)
    {
      s/\@<:\@/[/g;
      s/\@:>\@/]/g;
      s/\@\{:\@/(/g;
      s/\@:\}\@/)/g;
      s/\@S\|\@/\$/g;
      s/\@%:\@/#/g;
      s/\@&t\@//g;
      print $out $_;
    }
}

sub up_to_date ($)
{
  my ($req) = @_;

  return 0
    if ! $req->valid;

  my $tfile = $tcache . $req->id;
  my $ofile = $ocache . $req->id;

  return 0
    if ! -f $tfile || ! -f $ofile;

  my $tmtime = mtime ($tfile);
  my $omtime = mtime ($ofile);
  my ($file, $mtime) = ($tmtime < $omtime
            ? ($ofile, $omtime) : ($tfile, $tmtime));

  my @dep = @ARGV;

  if (grep { $_ eq '-' } @dep)
    { return 0 }

  handle_traces ($req, "$tmp/dependencies",
         ('include'    => '$1',
          'm4_include' => '$1'));
  my $deps = new Autom4te::XFile ("< " . open_quote ("$tmp/dependencies"));
  while ($_ = $deps->getline)
    {
      chomp;
      my $file = find_file ("$_?", @include);
      return 0

    if ! $file;
      push @dep, $file;
    }

  return up_to_date_p ($file, @dep);
}

sub freeze ($)
{
  my ($output) = @_;

  my $result = xqx ("$m4"
            . ' --fatal-warning'
            . join (' --include=', '', map { shell_quote ($_) } @include)
            . ' --define=divert'
            . " " . files_to_options (@ARGV)
            . ' </dev/null');
  $result =~ s/#.*\n//g;
  $result =~ s/^\n//mg;

  fatal "freezing produced output:\n$result"
    if $result;

  xsystem ("$m4"
       . ' --fatal-warning'
       . join (' --include=', '', map { shell_quote ($_) } @include)
       . " --freeze-state=" . shell_quote ($output)
       . " " . files_to_options (@ARGV)
       . ' </dev/null');
}

mktmpdir ('am4t');
load_configuration ($ENV{'AUTOM4TE_CFG'} || "$pkgdatadir/autom4te.cfg");
load_configuration ("$ENV{'HOME'}/.autom4te.cfg")
  if exists $ENV{'HOME'} && -f "$ENV{'HOME'}/.autom4te.cfg";
load_configuration (".autom4te.cfg")
  if -f ".autom4te.cfg";
parse_args;

if ($freeze)
  {
    freeze ($output);
    exit $exit_code;
  }

if (! -d "$cache")
  {
    mkdir "$cache", 0755
      or -d "$cache"
      or fatal "cannot create $cache: $!";
  }

$icache_file = new Autom4te::XFile $icache, O_RDWR|O_CREAT;
$icache_file->lock (LOCK_EX)
  if ($flock_implemented eq "yes");

Autom4te::C4che->load ($icache_file)
  if -f $icache && mtime ($icache) > mtime ($0)
                && Autom4te::C4che->good_version ($icache_file);

my $req = Autom4te::C4che->request ('input' => \@ARGV,
                    'path'  => \@include,
                    'macro' => [keys %trace, @preselect]);

$req->valid (0)
  if $force || ! up_to_date ($req);

verb "the trace request object is:\n" . $req->marshall;

handle_m4 ($req, keys %{$req->macro})
  if $force || ! $req->valid;

my $separator = "\n" . ('-' x 25) . " END OF WARNING " . ('-' x 25) . "\n\n";
handle_traces ($req, "$tmp/warnings",
           ('_m4_warn' => "\$1::\$f:\$l::\$2::\$3$separator"));
for (split (/\n*$separator\n*/o, contents ("$tmp/warnings")))
{
  my ($cat, $loc, $msg, $stacktrace) = split ('::', $_, 4);
  msg $cat, $loc, "warning: $msg",
    partial => ($stacktrace =~ /top level$/) + 0;
  for (split /\n/, $stacktrace)
    {
      my ($loc, $trace) = split (': ', $_, 2);
      msg $cat, $loc, $trace, partial => ($trace !~ /top level$/) + 0;
    }
}

if (%trace)
  {
    handle_traces ($req, $output, %trace);
  }
else
  {
    handle_output ($req, $output)
      if $force || mtime ($output) < mtime ($ocache . $req->id);
  }

$req->valid (1);
Autom4te::C4che->save ($icache_file);

exit $exit_code;
```

Ya reinstalé *Perl 5.34.0*, pero el problema sigue... Tampoco veo que exista algún archivo `Dumper.c` o `Dumper.pc`, pero sí existe `Dumper.pm`.

```
/usr/lib64/perl5/Data/Dumper.pm
```

Hice una reducción máxima del `makeinfo` para ver en qué línea daba el error, el script de *Perl* quedó así:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use File::Spec;
use File::Basename;
BEGIN
{
    my $lib_dir = File::Spec->catdir('/usr/share', 'texinfo');
    unshift @INC, $lib_dir;
    require Texinfo::ModulePath;
    Texinfo::ModulePath::init($lib_dir, '/usr/lib64/texinfo', 'installed' => 1);
}
use Texinfo::Common;
```

Error del `Dumper`:

> perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
> perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
> LANGUAGE = (unset),
> LC_ALL = (unset),
> LANG = "es_AR.UTF-8"
> are supported and installed on your system.
> perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
> Dumper.c: loadable library and perl binaries are mismatched (got handshake key 0xdb00080, needed 0xeb00080)

Dependiendo de qué línea remueva del script, da diferentes errores.

¿Cómo soluciono esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero hay que instalar Texinfo:

- https://mirrors.slackware.com/slackware/slackware64-14.2/slackware64/ap/texinfo-6.1-x86_64-1.txz

Luego copiar los archivos faltantes a `/usr/share/perl5`:

```sh
cp -vrf /usr/share/texinfo/*                                /usr/share/perl5
cp -vrf /usr/share/texinfo/lib/libintl-perl/lib/*           /usr/share/perl5
cp -vrf /usr/share/texinfo/lib/Text-Unidecode/lib/*         /usr/share/perl5
cp -vrf /usr/share/texinfo/lib/Unicode-EastAsianWidth/lib/* /usr/share/perl5
```

Ahora con esto el script ya no da error del `Dumper`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use File::Spec;
use File::Basename;
BEGIN
{
    my $lib_dir = File::Spec->catdir('/usr/share', 'texinfo');
    unshift @INC, $lib_dir;
    require Texinfo::ModulePath;
    Texinfo::ModulePath::init($lib_dir, '/usr/lib64/texinfo', 'installed' => 1);
}
use Texinfo::Common;
```

Pero si hago esto vuelve a dar el error del `Dumper`:

```
perl -e "use Texinfo::Convert::Converter"
```

Ahora voy al archivo `/usr/share/perl5/Texinfo/Convert/Converter.pm` y analizo la causa. El problema viene de aquí:

```
perl -e "use Texinfo::Report"
```

Voy al archivo `/usr/share/perl5/Texinfo/Report.pm`, vuelvo a analizar la causa... El problema es aquí:

```
perl -e "use Texinfo::Parser"
```

Voy a `/usr/share/perl5/Texinfo/Parser.pm`, vuelvo a analizar... El problema es aquí:

```
perl -e "use Data::Dumper"
```

Entonces, hay que ir al archivo `/usr/share/perl5/Data/Dumper.pm`, veo que si copio el archivo y le cambio el nombre a Dumper2, y lo uso desde *Perl*, no aparece el error.

```
cd /usr/share/perl5/Data/
cp Dumper.pm Dumper2.pm
perl -e "use Data::Dumper2"
```

Y si intento usar `Dumper3`, me dice que no existe y que puede estar en alguna carpeta.

```
perl -e "use Data::Dumper3"
```

> perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
> perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
> LANGUAGE = (unset),
> LC_ALL = (unset),
> LANG = "es_AR.UTF-8"
> are supported and installed on your system.
> perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
> Can't locate Texinfo/Parser3.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Texinfo::Parser3 module) (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5) at -e line 1.
> BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at -e line 1.

Veo la lista de carpetas por línea:

```
echo "/usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5" | tr " " "\n"

/usr/local/lib64/perl5
/usr/local/share/perl5
/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl
/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl
/usr/lib64/perl5
/usr/share/perl5
```

Ahora veo si existe el archivo buscado en cada una de las carpetas:

```
ls --color -lh /usr/local/lib64/perl5/Data/Dumper.pm
ls --color -lh /usr/local/share/perl5/Data/Dumper.pm
ls --color -lh /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/Data/Dumper.pm
ls --color -lh /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Data/Dumper.pm
ls --color -lh /usr/lib64/perl5/Data/Dumper.pm
ls --color -lh /usr/share/perl5/Data/Dumper.pm
```

Resultados:

```
ls --color -lh /usr/local/lib64/perl5/Data/Dumper.pm
```

> ls: cannot access '/usr/local/lib64/perl5/Data/Dumper.pm': No such file or directory

```
ls --color -lh /usr/local/share/perl5/Data/Dumper.pm
```

> ls: cannot access '/usr/local/share/perl5/Data/Dumper.pm': No such file or directory

```
ls --color -lh /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/Data/Dumper.pm
```

> -r--r--r-- 1 root root 44K Sep 18  2014 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/Data/Dumper.pm

```
ls --color -lh /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Data/Dumper.pm
```

> ls: cannot access '/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Data/Dumper.pm': No such file or directory

```
ls --color -lh /usr/lib64/perl5/Data/Dumper.pm
```

> -r--r--r-- 1 root root 46K May 21 13:47 /usr/lib64/perl5/Data/Dumper.pm

```
ls --color -lh /usr/share/perl5/Data/Dumper.pm
```

> -r--r--r-- 1 root root 46K May 21 13:47 /usr/share/perl5/Data/Dumper.pm

Ahora hay que hacer que exista solo un archivo `Dumper.pm`, entonces hay que renombrar los demás archivos. El que permanece con el mismo nombre es `/usr/share/perl5/Data/Dumper.pm`, es decir, el último.

```
cd /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/Data/
mv Dumper.pm Dumper4.pm

cd /usr/lib64/perl5/Data/
mv Dumper.pm Dumper4.pm
```

Con esto, el problema está solucionado.